# ring: read body of a http request as string

Tags: clojure, ring

When handling a http request inside a ring server, the body of the request-data is stored in the request-hashmap in the key `:body`. For instance as followed:

```
#object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x2d88a9aa "HttpInputOverHTTP@2d88a9aa"]
```

In case, I'm just interested in the raw text, how an I read out this object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`ring.util.request/body-string`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.request.html#var-body-string) to get the request body as a String.

```
(body-string request)
```

You need to remember that `InputStream` can be read only once so you might prefer replace the original `:body` with the read `String` instead so you can later access it again:

```
(defn wrap-body-string [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let [body-str (ring.util.request/body-string request)]
      (handler (assoc request :body (java.io.StringReader. body-str))))))
```

And add your middleware to wrap your handler:

```
(def app
  (wrap-body-string handler))
```

Comment: This is nice but it somehow breaks `wrap-params` from `ring.middleware.params`.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by `user1338062` you can simply call `slurp` on the body of the request.

```
(defn handler [request]
  (let [body (slurp (:body request))]))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are correct. Updated my response :)

Answer (score 0):

The `:body` of ring request must be an instance of `java.io.InputStream`.
So you can use reader + slurp to get a string out.

```
(defn is->str [is]
  (let [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader is)]
    (slurp rdr)))
```

Usage: `(is->str (:body request))`

Comment: `slurp` can consume `InputStream` directly, no need to wrap it in a reader.